# Removing the first line of each file from a wildcard?

Tags: bash, scripting, wildcard

I am trying to copy about 100 CSVs into a PostgreSQL database. The CSVs aren't formed perfectly for the database, so I have to do some editing, which I am trying to do on the fly with piping.

Because each CSV file has a header, I need to remove the first line to prevent the headers from being copied into the database as an entity.

My attempt at this was the following:

```
sed -e "s:\.00::g" -e "s/\"\"//g" *.csv | tail -n +2 | cut -d "," -f1-109 |
psql -d intelliflight_pg -U intelliflight -c "\COPY flights FROM stdin WITH DELIMITER ',' CSV"
```

The problem I'm having with this is that it treats `*.csv` as a single file, and only removes the first line of the first file it sees, and leaves the rest of the files alone.

**How can I get this to remove the first line of each individual file retrieved by the `*.csv` wildcard?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the sed and `tail` steps and use `find` to have per-file processing, then pipe the output of that to `cut` and `psql`:

```
find -name '*.csv' -exec sed '1d;s/\.00//g;s/""//g' {} \; | cut ...
```

This uses sed to remove the first line from each file, then does the substitutions on the rest of the files. Each file is processed, and the output of it all piped to `cut` and the rest of your commands.

Notice the single quotes around the sed argument, simplifying things somewhat with the quoting.

This also processes `.csv` files in subdirectories; if you don't want that, you have to limit recursion depth with

```
find -maxdepth 1 -name etc.
```

Comment: When I run that, I get: 
`find: missing argument to: '-exec'`

Comment: @Ephraim Sorry, just updated to remove the `find`, which wasn't necessary.

Comment: That still leaves the first line from subsequent files in. It's removing the first line of the first file, but not from the rest of them.

Comment: It might also be useful to tell you that I'm doing this on windows. I don't know if wildcards work differently in linux

Comment: @Ephraim Right, removing `find` was a mistake, I've reverted that now. How are you running this? Cygwin, MSYS Bash, Git Bash...?

Comment: I'm running this in "Command Prompt With Ruby and Rails". It seems to be able to run most common linux commands.

Comment: @Ephraim Hmm, little stumped here. Just a wild guess: quoting `{}` as in `'{}'`?

Comment: Ok, I ran it in cygwin, and it seemed to run without a problem. Not really sure why it gave me an error in Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails, but your solution works. Now I just have to figure out how to get psql running on cygwin.

Answer (score 2):

Can't test it right now but this should do :

```
awk -F, '
    FNR == 1 {next} 
    {
        gsub(/\.00/, "")
        gsub(/""/, "") 
        NF = 109
        print
    } 
' *.csv | psql ..
```

The `NF= 109` line will drop any field after 109.

Comment: Extra space in first `gsub`?

Comment: yes, thank you. I typed that out on my phone, and my keyboard likes to add spaces everywhere.